# iOS enabling AirPrint for uiwebview contents

Tags: iphone, xcode, printing, uiwebview, airprint

I am super new to XCode and App development. I currently am loading up a web based application in uiwebviews on the iPad. When one particular page is loaded, it displays a pdf file. *I would like to be able to print this pdf file using AirPrint.* I am looking for a simple solution. Currently the app I am working on has 6 files which it uses.

```
-ViewController.m
-ViewController.h
-MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard
-MainStoryboard_iPhone.storyboard
-AppDelegate.h
-AppDelegate.m
```

In the MainStoryboard files, there are many windows (graphical) which are liked to a central navigation system. If it is possible to spend some time to really explain what I need to do, and not 'take a look at this link.' I have programming experience, but never with XCode or any product related to Apple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Firstly I found a piece of code here, [iOS Air print for UIwebview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544733/ios-air-print-for-uiwebview), I had no idea how to implement this at the time, but then I did as follows.

*My application was a single view XCode project*

In my storyboard I inserted a button (on my navigation bar) and changed its Identifier to 'Action' then, making sure to have the 'tuxedo' editor view open, displaying my ViewController.m file, I clicked and dragged from the button to the ViewController.m file while holding down control. This inserted my IBAction method after asking for my buttons id.

`myActionButton`

Then I copied in the code specified in response 3 of the question. My ViewController.m looked something link this.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController()
@end

@implementation ViewController()
//Some stuff here
@end

@synthesize webView

-(IBAction)myActionButton:(id)sender{
UIPrintInfo *pi = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
pi.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
pi.jobName = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
pi.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;
pi.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;

UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
pic.printInfo = pi;
pic.showsPageRange = YES;
pic.printFormatter = webView.viewPrintFormatter;
[pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic2, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
    // indicate done or error
}];
}
```

Also in my ViewController.h file

```
#import ...
@interface ViewController : ...
{
IBOutlet UIWebView *webView
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView
@end
```

I didn't setup the webviews so I am not 100% sure on how they are created, but there is a good series for beginners on youtube at [HackLife87](http://www.youtube.com/user/HackLife87?feature=watch) which shows how to make a single view app. I think XCode Tutorial Video #7 involves setting up views.

Since I am extremely green to XCode and IPad app development, I managed to solve my problem by combining knowledge from watching the aforementioned XCode tutorial videos and then implementing the solution provided on stackoverflow by [Hafthor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4489/hafthor).